# How to check if a column type is defined?

Tags: tables, conditionals, columns

Column types for tables can be defined and overwritten with `\newcolumntype`.
I would like to know if a column type is already defined for an example which shall only be executed in the case where the columntype is defined.

EDIT:
Similar to the answer of egreg I had also created this code:

```
\newcommand\isColumntypeDefined[1]{%
  \providebool{\tpl@coltype@#1}
  \ifcsdef{NC@find@\string#1}{
    \setboolean{\tpl@coltype@#1}{true}%
  }{%
    \setboolean{\tpl@coltype@#1}{false}
  }%
  \boolean{\tpl@coltype@#1}%
}
```

but that fails because `\tpl@coltype@#1` does not create a valid command. This problem is related to [latex @temps(wa) commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35530/latex-tempswa-commands).
It would be great to know how to make this code compileable.

EDIT2: I changed the whole code to etoolbox definitions and finally ended with this

```
% Create list of predefined columntypes
\expandafter\let\csname columntype@l\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname columntype@c\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname columntype@r\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname columntype@p\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname columntype@m\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname columntype@b\endcsname\@empty

\newcommand\CheckIfColumntypeDefined[1]{%
  \providebool{tpl@coltype@#1}
  \ifcsdef{NC@find@\string#1}%
    {\setbool{tpl@coltype@#1}{true}}%
    {\ifcsdef{columntype@\string#1}
      {\setbool{tpl@coltype@#1}{true}}%
      {\setbool{tpl@coltype@#1}{false}}%
    }%
}

\newcommand\isColumntypeDefined[1]{tpl@coltype@#1}

\newcommand\IfColumntypeDefined[3]{%
  \CheckIfColumntypeDefined{#1}
  \ifboolexpr{ bool{\isColumntypeDefined{#1}} }{#2}{#3}%
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The instruction

```
\newcolumntype{N}{...}
```

defines the command `\NC@find@N`. You can check it with

```
\ifcsname NC@find@\string#1\endcsname
```

A `\safenewcolumntype` command can be defined by

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@gobbleoptandone[2][]{}
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@l\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@c\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@r\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@p\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@m\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@b\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@@\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@!\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@|\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@<\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@>\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\let\csname safenct@=\endcsname\@empty
\def\safenct@error#1{\PackageError{mypackage}
    {Column type `\string#1' already defined}
    {The column type you're trying to define is already\MessageBreak
     existent; I'll ignore this new definition}}
\newcommand{\safenewcolumntype}[1]{%
  \@tempswafalse
  \ifcsname NC@find@\string#1\endcsname
    \safenct@error{#1}\@tempswatrue
  \fi
  \ifcsname safenct@#1\endcsname
    \safenct@error{#1}\@tempswatrue
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi{\@gobbleoptandone}{\newcolumntype{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

If the column type is already defined we put before the rest of the token list the command `\@gobbleoptandone` that will gobble the optional argument and the mandatory one: `\safenewcolumntype{l}[1]{...}` would become

```
\@gobbleoptandone[1]{...}
```

and all is good.

Otherwise we put `\newcolumntype{#1}` that will perform its duty. Of course it would be better to patch the original `\newcolumntype` command.

## Patching the original definition

With the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, we redefine the `\newcolumntype` command in such a way that it checks whether the column type is already defined or not and, in the former case, it disallows redefining the column type. One could define also a `\renewcolumntype` command, but it doesn't seem this important.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@gobbleoptandone[2][]{}
\def\newcolumntype#1{%
  \@tempswafalse
  \edef\NC@char{\string#1}%
  \@ifundefined{NC@find@\NC@char}%
    {\@tfor\next:=<>clrmbp@!|\do
      {\if\next\NC@char
         \PackageError{safenct}{`\NC@char' is a primitive column type}
           {You're trying to redefine a primitive column type;\MessageBreak
            the redefinition will be ignored}%
         \global\@safenct@deftrue
       \fi}%
    \if@tempswa\else\NC@list\expandafter{\the\NC@list\NC@do#1}\fi}%
    {\PackageError{safenct}{Column `\NC@char' is already defined}
       {This column type is already defined;\MessageBreak
        the redefinition will be ignored}%
     \@tempswatrue}%
  \if@tempswa
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\@gobbleoptandone}
  {\@namedef{NC@find@\NC@char}##1#1{\NC@{##1}}%
   \@ifnextchar[{\newcol@{\NC@char}}{\newcol@{\NC@char}[0]}}
}

\makeatother

\newcolumntype{N}{>{Y}l<{Z}}
\newcolumntype{N}{r}
\newcolumntype{l}{r}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{N}
xxxx\\
x\\
xx
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When `\newcolumntype{x}` is scanned, the routine sets the scratch conditional to false and checks if `x` is among the primitive column types and, if it is, issues an error message and sets the temporary conditional to true. Then it checks whether `x` is among the "derived" column types, that is, defined via `\newcolumntype` itself. If it is, the scratch conditional is again set to false. Finally, as in the code presented before, the proper action is taken: if the conditional is false the following part of the code for `\newcolumntype` is gobbled, otherwise the definition is performed.

Comment: I had also found this definition in array.sty. Is it also valid without array.sty? Also see my edit above.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech No, it isn't. Actually the "primitive" column types pass the test! The task is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Although this does not directly answer your question, the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) provides `\showcols` which (according to the [`array` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf)) does the following:

> A list of all the currently active `\newcolumntype` definitions is sent
>   to the terminal and `.log` file.

For example, if your `.tex` file contains:

```
\newcolumntype{X}{l}
\newcolumntype{Y}{@{}c<{\hspace{1ex}}@{\ }}
\showcols
```

your `.log` file will contain

```
Column X -> l
Column Y -> @{}c<{\hspace {1ex}}@{\ }
```

Comment: I know, but I want to use this test within the document code.