# Code fails when loading boolexpr

Tags: conditionals, incompatibility, etoolbox

I use this code to check for existing column style (see also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35527/how-to-check-if-a-column-type-is-defined))

But it fails as soon as I load the package `boolexpr`. Is this incompatible with `etoolbox`?

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname columntype@p\endcsname\@empty
\newcommand\CheckIfColumntypeDefined[1]{%
  \providebool{tpl@coltype@#1}
  \ifcsdef{NC@find@\string#1}%
    {\setbool{tpl@coltype@#1}{true}}%
    {\ifcsdef{columntype@\string#1}
      {\setbool{tpl@coltype@#1}{true}}%
      {\setbool{tpl@coltype@#1}{false}}%
    }%
}
\newcommand\isColumntypeDefined[1]{tpl@coltype@#1}
\newcommand\IfColumntypeDefined[3]{%
  \CheckIfColumntypeDefined{#1}
  \ifboolexpr{ bool{\isColumntypeDefined{#1}} }{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\RequirePackage{boolexpr}

\begin{document}
\IfColumntypeDefined{p}{p column defined}{p not defined}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since both define `\ifboolexpr`, I guess they don't go well together. :(

Comment: That's because both define similar commands. Why do you need [`boolexpr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/boolexpr)?

Comment: @Werner: for a switch structure as linked in the comment of the first answer.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: If you use the load order `\RequirePackage{boolexpr}\let\ifboolexpr\relax\RequirePackage{etoolbox}`, can you still use the switch structure? I don't have an example to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answer this question also in relation to the commands. First of all both packages define the command `\ifboolexpr`. The package `boolexpr` overwrite the existings definition by his own.
This can be seen by the warning message defined in line 78 of `boolexpr.sty`

```
\PackageWarning{boolexpr}{\string\ifboolexpr\space has been defined
                          by etoolbox (I suppose) - Overwritting}
```

So your test which works with `etoolbox` fails because at the point of executing the definition of the package `boolexpr` will be used. The package `boolexpr` isn't such stable as `etoolbox`.

I recommend the using of `etoolbox` instead of `boolexpr`.

Comment: I use boolexp only because it provides a nice switch syntax (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29133/how-to-create-switch-structure-comparing-strings-in-latex) which etoolbox does not provide.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: For such things I use `xifinlist` provided by etoolbox. (similar to ifstreq)

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech I've added an answer to that question; it uses `expl3` and is independent of `boolexpr` and `etoolbox`.