# keyvalue with kvoptions and switch structure

Tags: conditionals, programming, key-value

I am using kvoptions for a key-value syntax. However I need a switch syntax for the evaluation. Since boolexpr is problamatic (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41769/code-fails-when-loading-boolexpr)) I use now the other solution of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29133/how-to-create-switch-structure-comparing-strings-in-latex).

However the switch is not working as expected (always results in the same value).

This is the code that I use:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}  % options
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds} % string comparison

\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=demo,prefix=demo@}

% parallel, stacked
\DeclareStringOption[stacked]{style}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions{demo}

\newcommand{\PrintDemoUsingKeys}{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\demo@style}{parallel}=0%
    parallel%
  \else\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\demo@style}{stacked}=0%
    stacked%
  \else%
     \PackageError{templatedemo}{%
       \MessageBreak%
       value >\tplbugs@style< unkown \MessageBreak%
     }{}%
  \fi\fi%
}%

% Print code and result using the key-value syntax
\newcommand{\PrintDemo}[2][]{%
%  #1  is the optional keyval argument
%  #2  is a mandatory argument
\begingroup%
\setkeys{demo}{#1}%
%  Do  stuff  with  #2
\PrintDemoUsingKeys%
\endgroup% 
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\PrintDemo{style=parallel}

\PrintDemo{style=stacked}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your key setting is inside a group, so `\PrintDemoUsingKeys` will never see any change.

Comment: @JosephWright: that is right, but even that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your macros: you say

```
\setkeys{demo}{#1}
```

and `#1` is the optional argument to `\PrintDemo`, which is by default empty, according to the definition. So nothing is evaluated, of course, if the call is `\PrintDemo{whatever}`.

But also calling

```
\PrintDemo[style=parallel]{whatever}
```

you'll get a surprise: because of the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` pair, the value of `\demo@style` will be reverted to the default `stacked` just after executing `\endgroup`, so before `\PrintDemoUsingKeys` is expanded. Thus it should be

```
\newcommand{\PrintDemo}[2][]{%
%  #1  is the optional keyval argument
%  #2  is a mandatory argument
  \setkeys{demo}{#1}%
  %  Do  stuff  with  #2
  \PrintDemoUsingKeys
}
```

called as

```
\PrintDemo[style=parallel]{whatever}
```

If you want to call this as `\PrintDemo{style=parallel}`, just change the definition into

```
\newcommand{\PrintDemo}[1]{%
  \setkeys{demo}{#1}%
  \PrintDemoUsingKeys
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I want to call it using `\PrintDemo{style=parallel}`. I copied the code for the optional argument, but can not remember where it is from.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Don't define an optional argument, then.

Comment: The code is from http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94wright-keyval.pdf

Comment: It works with your code, nevertheless I would like to discuss how the solution of the documentation is supposed to work.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech The authors explains clearly that they want to limit the action of setting the keys to that particular instance. If you want to do that, then put `\PrintDemoUsingKeys` *inside* the `\begingroup`-`\endgroup` pair.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the code in the documentation completely (I thought the second example would be an improvement over the first one). Only here with your example it became clear how it is supposed to be used.