# Re-newing a column type

Tags: tables, warnings

Package [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) has a `\newcolumntype` but seemingly no `\renewcolumntype`. But it makes a lot of sense to have a column type `X` whose meaning could be changed depending on context. When one does `\newcolumntype` again, it works, the only thing is that an innocent warning is written to the log. Is there some official way I missed from reading the doc which would allow of genuinely renewing an `array-declared` column type?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35527/how-to-check-if-a-column-type-is-defined

Comment: The intention was you'd just use `\newcolumntype` is it that you want to suppress the warning?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle suppressing the warning would be just fine indeed. The idea is that the user employs some access macro which is converted by the (would-be) package into the use of `\newcolumntype`, where the identifier is one and the same, private to the package, and to not worry the user, suppressing the warning would be just fine.

Comment: There is a silence package that can turn off \PackageWarning in general or (I think) for specific packages

Comment: or just use some command like `\let\NC@find@X\relax` to undefine the column before defining it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, thanks. I got into this from my code on [matrices](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112599/perform-matrix-operations-addition-product-transpose-etc-in-latex/143035#143035). The `\MATdisplay` macro sets up a simple `*{N}c` array preamble, where `N` is the variable number of columns, and I wanted to make it easy for the user to replace `c` by `r` for example. So currently the type is called `X` and renewed with the resulting warning.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this will be ok with the `\NC@list` ?

Comment: If the change is occasional, you might want to use a 1-column `multicolumn` instead of redefinitions: `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
column1 & column2 & column 3\\hline
A & B & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{C}\\end{tabular}`

Comment: @masu thanks, but the contents are not to be modified, only the preamble.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle here is the current code I use `\newcolumntype\MATdisplaycoltype {c}
\newcolumntype\MATdisplaypreamble [1]{@{}*{#1[J]}\MATdisplaycoltype@{}}`. I use the possibility of having a column type stand for an entire preamble, and furthermore to have a parameter (the `#1[J]` will expand to a number of columns). The user should be able to easily switch `\MATdisplaycoltype` from `c` to  `r`. But redefining it issues the warning.

Comment: Using command names for columns rather than letters sort of works by accident but was never the intention:-) Just patch \newcolumntype to undefine \csname NC@find@\string#1\endcsname as noted above. You ask if it is OK to do that, just because I wrote that code a quarter of a century ago doesn't necessarily mean I've forgotten how it works:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am in awe because I quickly forget code I wrote only two weeks earlier :) and also because you write code which works in extended contexts! I will undefine the corresponding `\NC@find@\stuff`, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elaborating on David's idea:

```
\newcommand\undefcolumntype[1]{\expandafter\let\csname NC@find@#1\endcsname\relax}
\newcommand\forcenewcolumntype[1]{\undefcolumntype{#1}\newcolumntype{#1}}
```

I don't call it `\renewcolumntype` since it works even if the column type is not defined (which is a different behaviour from `\renewcommand`). Whence the name `\forcenewcolumntype`.

*Thanks to [jfbu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4686/jfbu) for spotting out a crucial typo in the code.*